# How safe is it to use blkid for determining unformatted disks and formatting those?

Tags: disk, blkid

For an automatic volume mount Ansible script, I use https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/filesystem_module.html to detect and format unformatted disks to allow mounting. That Ansible module again relies on `blkid` for filesystem detection.

I have a hard time finding information about which filesystems `blkid` can safely detect and which not. I took a look at https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/blkid.8.html but it doesn't mention an complete list of recognized filesystems. Is it even possible to give a complete list?

Of course I do not want to overwrite any data that might be on the volume no matter how obscure the filesystem might be (I can't control what's on the volumes). Therefore, I am currently planning to make the automatic volume formatting a default off option. However, it would be good to be able to give a list of clearly recognized filesystems so users can make an informed decision.